# Syncfusion Diagram nodes custom properties

Tags: syncfusion

In EJ2 .NET Core Syncfusion Diagram component how can I extend the Node object with custom properties and save them into database. The documentation describes only the saving / loading of the whole diagram. Ideally, I would like upon each node selection the custom properties, coming from datatable, to be shown in the right pane as in angular diagram builder example. Is there any event which will notify about user selection?

Answer (score 1):

We can extend the node object with custom properties by using addInfo property. Please find below code example for how to use addInfo property of node.

```
Dictionary<string, object> addInfo = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            addInfo.Add("Text", "New");

            Nodes.Add(new DiagramNode()
            {
                Id = "NewIdea",
                OffsetY = 80,
                OffsetX = 340,
                Height = 60,
                AddInfo =addInfo,
                Shape = new { type = "Flow", shape = "Terminator" }
            });
```

The selection change event gets fired, while selecting the node. In that event, the args.newValue parameter assist to identify which node is get selected. Please find below code example for how to use the selectionChange event.

```
<ejs-diagram id="container" width="100%" height="700px" selectionChange="selectionChange" nodes="ViewBag.nodes" connectors="ViewBag.connectors">
                    <e-diagram-snapsettings horizontalGridlines="ViewBag.gridLines" verticalGridlines="ViewBag.gridLines"></e-diagram-snapsettings>
                </ejs-diagram>

function selectionChange(args) {
var node = args.newValue[0];
// define your logic here
       }
```

For more information about selectionChange event, please refer to below help documentation link

Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/diagram/iSelectionChangeEventArgs/

Regards,

Ramya T